# Optimize tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that is executed in 35s, which is waaaaay too long.

Here are the 3 tables concerned by the query (each table is approx. 13000 lines long, and should be much longer in the future) :

Table 1 : Domains

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `domain` (
  `id_domain` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domain_domain` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `projet_domain` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_crea_domain` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_expi_domain` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active_domain` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `remarques_domain` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_domain`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table 2 : Keywords

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kw` (
  `id_kw` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kw_kw` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `clics_kw` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cpc_kw` float(11,3) NOT NULL,
  `date_kw` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_kw`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table 3 : Linking between domain and keyword

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kw_domain` (
  `id_kd` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kw_kd` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `domain_kd` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `selected_kd` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_kd`),
  KEY `kw_to_domain` (`kw_kd`,`domain_kd`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The query is as follows :

```
SELECT ng.*, kd.*, kg.*
FROM domain ng
    LEFT JOIN kw_domain kd ON kd.domain_kd = ng.id_domain
    LEFT JOIN kw kg ON kg.id_kw = kd.kw_kd
GROUP BY ng.id_domain 
ORDER BY kd.selected_kd DESC, kd.id_kd DESC
```

Basically, it selects all domains, with, for each one of these domains, the last associated keyword.

Does anyone have an idea on how to optimize the tables or the query ?

Comment: This does not select the last associated keyword.  It selects an arbitrary keyword.  The query does not do what you think it is doing.  In general, you should not use `group by` and have unaggregated, non-grouped columns in the `select`.

Comment: The query returns the last associated keyword because another query (during update or insert) sets selected_kd=0 for all keywords reviously associated to  the domain.

Comment: The pernicious MySQL extension to `GROUP BY` has caught you. *Please* read this:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html  

Also, pro tip: Never use `SELECT *` or any variant of it in software. Especially with `JOIN` commands, it returns a lot of redundant columns and slows things down. Optimization of JOIN queries often can be done with compound indexes, but `SELECT *` makes that very difficult.

Comment: Why the downvote 1.5 years later ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will get the last keyword, according to your logic:

```
select ng.*,
       (select kw_kd
        from kw_domain kd
        where kd.domain_kd = ng.id_domain and kd.selected_kd = 1
        order by kd.id_kd desc
        limit 1
       ) as kw_kd
from domain ng;
```

For performance, you want an index on `kw_domain(domain_kd, selected_kd, kw_kd)`.  In this case, the order of the fields matters.

You can use this as a subquery to get more information about the keyword:

```
select ng.*, kg.*
from (select ng.*,
             (select kw_kd
              from kw_domain kd
              where kd.domain_kd = ng.id_domain and kd.selected_kd = 1
              order by kd.id_kd desc
              limit 1
             ) as kw_kd
      from domain ng
     ) ng left join
     kw kg
     on kg.id_kw = ng.kw_kd;
```

In MySQL, `group by` can have poor performance, so this might work better, particularly with the right indexes.

Comment: Works like a charm (it was still very long until I set the index as you suggested). Thanks a lot !